# List.AddRange inline declaration

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, delphi-prism, oxygene

This may seem an easy question, but not to me, also a search has led to nothing. Up until now the only .net programming I have done is with Delphi Prism. With Prism I can do things like:

```
var l := new List<String>(['A','B','C']);
```

or

```
var l := new List<String>;
l.AddRange(['A','B','C'];
```

but can I do a similar thing in C#, or do I have to do it like:

```
var a = new String[] {"A","B","C"};
var l = new List<String>(a);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
 var l=new List<String>() {"A","B","C"};
```

this will work

Comment: Following recent revisions to the C# language, you would drop the (). The current syntax is --- var l = new List<string> {"A","B","C"};

Answer (score 6):

collection initializer:

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
};
```

or correct ctor (mixed with collection initializer):

```
var list = new List<string>(new [] { "A", "B", "C" });
```

- [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0cyc8ex.aspx) for ctor infos
- [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for collection initializer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) to achieve desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, use collection initializers. In addition, if you are looking to convert from string[] to List , you can use the ToList() extension method in the System.Linq namespace like so:

```
string[] s = { "3", "4", "4"};
List<string> z = s.ToList();
```